# Extract words using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string query and I want to match and extract specif words.
when I have this word `word.EXACT` extract the container of this word

like `MESH.EXACT("blood glucose monitoring")` extract the word `"blood glucose monitoring"`

- words.exact("N-Words") -> result `"N-Words"`
- words.exact(N-Words) -> result `N-Words`

`Query_Input= (EMB.EXACT("insulin treatment")) and (MESH.EXACT("blood glucose monitoring")) OR "Self-Monitoring of Blood Glucose”`

the output needs to be like that

Query_out=`"insulin treatment" "blood glucose monitoring" "Self-Monitoring of Blood Glucose”`

this Demo has my regexp and my regex : https://regex101.com/r/rqpmXr/15

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/3z2qafc6/2/

Comment: you answer near to my result but in this case is wrong https://jsfiddle.net/3z2qafc6/4/  because the out put  need to be `"blood glucose monitoring" words "blood glucose monitoring"`

Comment: Use https://jsfiddle.net/3z2qafc6/5/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i will considere your answer the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\w+\.EXACT\(([^)]*)\)/g
```

and replace with `$1`, placeholder holding Group 1 value. See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Bdxbtg/1).

**Pattern details**

- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `\.EXACT\(` - a literal `.EXACT(` substring
- `([^)]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `)` (you may use `[^()]*` in case you need to make sure you are staying within 1 set of `(...)`)
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the JS demo:

```js
var s = 'MESH.EXACT("blood glucose monitoring") words tt.EXACT("blood glucose monitoring") ';
var rx = /\w+\.EXACT\(([^)]*)\)/g;
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = s.replace(rx, "$1");
```

```html
<div id="result" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
(?<=\w\.EXACT\()[^)]+
```

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BS3nwr/3). Match any char that is not a closing parenthesis, `[^)]+`, only when preceded by `\w\.EXACT(`.

If you want a substitution you could capture the above match and use `\1`  (note the trailing space) for the repacement:

```
.*(?<=\w\.EXACT\()([^)]+).*\n|.*
```

as shown here: https://regex101.com/r/BS3nwr/4

Edit: As was brought to my attention in one of the comments, look-behinds (`?<=`) are not supported in some web browsers so you could use (note this regex is slower (requires more steps) than the previous one):

```
\w+\.EXACT\(([^)]+).*\n|.*?
```

Comment: Lookbehinds are not yet a standard feature in all browsers. It will only work in the latest Chrome versions for the time being, no idea when other browsers will catch up.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe this would work :

`.EXACT\((.*?)\)`

Working Example : https://regex101.com/r/uQj2vv/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an executable Javascript example which extracts the output you specified from the input you specified:

```js
let input = "(EMB.EXACT(\"insulin treatment\")) and (MESH.EXACT(\"blood glucose monitoring\")) OR \"Self-Monitoring of Blood Glucose\"";

let re = /(?:EXACT\(("[^"]+")\)|OR\s*("[^"]+"))/g;

let Query_out = [];
while ((match = re.exec(input)) !== null) {
  Query_out.push(match[1] ? match[1] : match[2]);
}

console.log(Query_out.join(" "));
```